# IIS 8 time did not change when we modify the server time due to Daylight saving time

Tags: iis, iis-8, gmt

I  am using IIS-8 under Windows Server 2012 R2. and the time for both the IIS & windows server were exactly the same. but this week we changed our server time be adding one hour for daylight saving time. this caused our IIS time to be different than the real time.

now I am using a schedule tool named hangfire which execute background jobs and it is hosted under IIS, and I am allowing users to determine the schedule time using a UI.

The problem is that currently if we set the schedule time for example to be 18:00 , it will be executed at 19:00. also the IIS logs time is one hour pass the actual time. so can anyone advice on this please?how i can force the IIS time and date to be in-sync with our windows server time and date?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do you have IIS applications running under a service account? Try logging in with the service account creds and check the regional settings for that account.

Comment: i login to the server where the iis is installed and the server time is one hour plus the time inside the IIS logs .. so the server time is let say 10:30 am while inside the iis logs the time is 09:30

Comment: This could be an issue with IIS's log file format.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/271196.

Also, I don't think it's as desirable to manually change the server time to account for DST versus just setting the clock to auto-adjust for DST. That setting is available under "Change time zone..." in the "Date and Time" control panel.

Comment: i do not think this is an issue with iis logs file !!! as i mentioned in my question,, now i am using a third part tool to execute back ground jobs and if i specify that i need to run a background job at 10 am the actual execution time will be 11 am.. so seems iis time is not adjust with the server time ..

Comment: Have you attempted to review the regional/datetime settings for the service account with which the application's application pool is running? If the application pool is running under "UserDude123" for instance, it might be a good idea to try running it under another account like "Network Service" to see if the time issue is account related.

Also, it would appear that the "hangfire" application you're using has some of its own time adjustment functionalities.

Can you elaborate on any steps you've taken in attempting to address this issue?